# ISS Life Support Consumable use rate

Tags: iss, life-support

At what rate does the International Space Station, (ISS), consume life support resources and other consumables?

I'm attempting to calculate long term life supoprt requirements for a system based on ISS lifesupport technologies.  But while I can find lots of news articles about new recycling equipment being installed, actual use rates...?

Comment: I think the best approach would be resupply mission cargo manifests, if you can get your hands on some. Divide by period between resupplies, you have resupply rate which is about the same as consumption rate.